# Sending text and getting answer from JavaScript to Spring

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

I have a simple NodeJs and SpringBoot projects and i want to send a simple text from the first one to the next. Here is how hbs form looks like:

```
index.hbs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<HEAD>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Project</title>
</HEAD>
<body>
<label>Type text</label>
<textarea id ="someID" name = "fieldName"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="sendToSpring()">Send and get</button>
<br>
<p id="score"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller for this form:

```
let value;
function getFormText(){
  value = document.getElementById('someID').value;
}
//Here is a method when i want to send "value", and get some answer. 
function sendToSpring(){
}
```

Method in Spring RestController:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data")
    public void getJavaScriptdata((@RequestParam String text)) throws JsonProcessingException {
    System.out.println("Here is the answer from JS side: "+text)
}
```

I know that propably i have to use Fetch() or XMLHttpRequest, but i'm struggling with it for a few days and i didn't get nothing. :/ I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: just wanna say, pick fetch over XMLHttpRequest

Comment: What exactly do you need whether it is JavaScript Ajax call or something else?